# Does $\sum 1-e^{-a_n}<\infty$ implies $\sum{a_n} <\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose we have a positive sequence $(a_n)$. Suppose also $\sum 1-e^{-a_n}$ converges. Can we deduce that $\sum{a_n}$ coverges?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Notice that you must have $1-e^{-a_n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, or equivalently $a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. But then, using a first-order Taylor approximation for $e^{-x}$ around $0$, you have
$$
1-e^{-a_n} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} a_n
$$
and you can conclude by theorems of comparison that the series $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n (1-e^{-a_n})$ have same nature.

Comment: you can just use \to for limits, that long arrow looks a little bit weird to me :)

Comment: @Giovanni The point was to write the $n\to\infty$ below.

Comment: oh, you are right, I haven't noticed that! nevermind!

Comment: Also, small comment: the assumption that $(a_n)$ is positive is used to apply the comparison theorems (which only hold for series with non-negative terms).

Answer (score 1):

Consider Taylor expansion, $e^{-a_n}=1-a_n+\frac{a_n^2}{2!}.....$, and $1-e^{-a_n}=a_n-\frac{a_n^2}{2!}....$. For small $a_n$, $1-e^{-a_n}>a_n/2$, thus $\sum a_n$ converges.